# Splitting js object based on new property

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to split this object based on a common new property 'subject'.
There could be multiple subjects in a single object in the original data. But in the final data, it must have a single subject and the marks associated with it.

```
let x = {
  'Name': 'Ajay',
  'Maths': 0,
  'English': 26,
}
```

and the expected output is

```
let y = [{
  'Name' : 'Ajay',
  'Marks' : 0,
  'Subject' : 'Maths'
},{
  'Name' : 'Ajay',
  'Marks' : 26,
  'Subject' : 'English'
}]
```

It's basically splitting each object into multiple objects.
Could anyone help me out with an approach to this?

I went with this approach in the end of iterating through the keys and skipping 'name' property.

```
for (let i of Object.keys(x)) {
let temp = {};
if (i === "Name") {
  continue;
} else {
  temp = {
    Name: x["Name"],
    Subject: i,
    Marks: x[i],
  };
}
```

Comment: Start with iterating over all properties of `x`. If the current property is `Name`, you want to ignore it, for all others, you want to create a new object and add it to your result array.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Have you for example tried to use [`entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)? Please provide your code so we can tell what you did wrong.

Comment: `typescript` tag is superfluous

Answer (score 4):

You could destructure the common property and map the other entries.

```js
const
    convert = ({ Name, ...o }) => Object
        .entries(o)
        .map(([Subject, Marks]) => ({ Name, Subject, Marks })),
    data = { Name: 'Ajay', Maths: 0, English: 26 },
    result = convert(data);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to extract name and then process remaining properties. [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) gives you key-value pairs:

```js
let x = {
  'Name': 'Ajay',
  'Maths': 0,
  'English': 26,
};

const { Name, ...subjects } = x;

const result = Object.entries(subjects).map(([Subject, Marks]) => ({Name, Subject, Marks}));
console.log(result);
```